# android - Programming a button to re reload the activity

Tags: java, android

How do I create a button to reload the Fragment or the activity in java ??

For example, if data is failed to fetch from the server or Internet connection fails, the button is pressed and retried ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: in this case you have not to reload fragment but the “view” that shows your data

Comment: from the same fragment or same activity you want to reload ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about activity and reload the same activity then add a button on your activity

```
//the layout on which you are working
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);

    //set the properties for button
    Button btnTag = new Button(this);
    btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btnTag.setText("Button");
    btnTag.setId(some_random_id);

    //add button to the layout
    layout.addView(btnTag);
```

then add a onclick listner to the button

```
btnTag.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

   finish();

  startActivity(getIntent());

    }
});
```

Comment: As I said before.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the same activity using an intent. Do not know if it starts the whole process. Maybe it would be necessary to reset someway before.